# How to manipulate time in HH:MM format

Tags: perl

I simply want to add 15  minute increments to a variable that holds data in HH:MM format in 24 hour clock mode.

I tried using Time:Piece which lets me format the time, but I'm not able to run conditions or manipulate the value since it forces me to use the strptime method. Is there a way around this?

In the code below, the condition fails because it is not able to read 00:45 from $start_time.

```
my $value = "00:15";
my $format = '%H:%M';
my $start_time = Time::Piece->strptime($value, $format);

print $start_time->strftime($format). "\n";

$start_time += 60 * 15;

print $start_time->strftime($format). "\n";

$start_time += 60 * 15;

print $start_time->strftime($format). "\n";

if ($start_time eq "00:45") {
    print "hello!\n";
}
```

Comment: Is this just times, or is they include a date component as well?

Comment: Your last line should read: `if ($start_time->strftime($format) eq "00:45")`

Comment: I don't know much about `Time::Piece` but `Date::Calc` is simple to use and can accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: no, there are no dates, just hours and minutes. I'm creating a comma delimited file with times based on certain conditions so that I can create schedules.

Comment: @ChrisCharley - yes, I figured this was probably the solution, but it seems very cumbersome and wondered if there is a simpler way.

Comment: It is a time or a duration? It's impossible to add 15 minutes to a time without knowing the date and time zone. For example, 15 minutes pass 1:45 is 1:00 once a year in my time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for my $h (0..23) {
   for my $m (0, 15, 30, 45) {
      push @times, sprintf("%02d:%02d", $h, $m);
   }
}
```

But using this, your schedule will be wrong twice a year if you inhabit somewhere with Daylight Saving Time.

Handling DST requires knowing the date and the timezone for which you are preparing the schedule.

Comment: This is what I needed, thanks! I am only generating a list of time intervals to be read by scheduling software that will use the machine's local time, so it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The most advanced module for date and time manipulation is a DateTime module:

```
use DateTime; 
my $t = DateTime->new( year=>0, hour=>0, minute=>0 ); 
for (1..10){ 
  print $t->strftime( "%H:%M\n" ); 
  $t = $t->add( minutes=>15 );
}
```

The module Date::Calc is very good too.

Comment: I'm using ActivePerl for Windows, and DateTime seems to be unavailable. I can try using DateCalc.

Comment: I'm using ActivePerl for Windows too and DateTime is here.